# Why is the entered text in my working JTextField not visible / selectable?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am currently doing the CS106A Stanford Java course for beginners. I am stuck at the handout number 7, requiring me to create a simple program that draws GRects with a GLabel on them on the canvas and then allows me to drag them around, remove them again or clear the whole canvas. In order to add such a box, I have added a JTextField in the SOUTH to enter the name of the box, and ADD / REMOVE / CLEAR buttons.

Entering a name into the textfield to add a box works. My problem is that the text I type into the JTextField, though recorded (since it shows up on the new box) is not displayed in the JTextField itself, so I do not see what I typed until I hit "ADD" and I read it on the box itself.

Here's my code:

```
    package handout07Interactors;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.swing.*;

import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Box_Diagram extends GraphicsProgram{

    public void init() {
        displayButtons();
        addActionListeners();

        //TODO make draggable

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("ADD")) {

            //create box
            GCompound canvasBox = createBox(tf.getText());

            //add box to HashMap
            map.put(tf.getText(), canvasBox);

            //add box to canvas
            int x = (int) (getWidth() - canvasBox.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (int) (getHeight() - canvasBox.getHeight()) / 2;
            add(canvasBox, x, y);

        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("REMOVE")) {

            //remove box with name
            if (map.get(tf.getText()) != null) {remove(map.get(tf.getText()));}; //if box exists, remove it 

        } else {

            for( String name: map.keySet() )
            {
                remove(map.get(name));
            }



        }

    }

    private GCompound createBox(String text) {

        // GCompound
        GCompound box = new GCompound();

        // create GRect
        GRect rect = new GRect(BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT);
        box.add(rect);

        // add GLabel
        GLabel label = new GLabel(text);
        int x = (int) (rect.getWidth() - label.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = 30; //manual entry, somehow calculation didn't work as it does for width
        box.add(label, x, y);

        map.put(text, box);

        return box;

    }

    private void displayButtons() {

        //label
        add(new JLabel("Name:"), SOUTH);

        //textfield
        tf = new JTextField(30);
        tf.addActionListener(this);
        add(tf, SOUTH);

        //ADD REMOVE CLEAR
        add(new JButton("ADD"), SOUTH);
        add(new JButton("REMOVE"), SOUTH);
        add(new JButton("CLEAR"), SOUTH);

    }

    //IVARS
    private JTextField tf;
    public static final int BOX_WIDTH = 100;
    public static final int BOX_HEIGHT = 50;
    public HashMap<String, GCompound> map = new HashMap<String, GCompound>();



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding 5 different components (the label, text field, and the 3 buttons) to the same place in the layout (the SOUTH section of your border layout).

You should add these 5 components to another JPanel, using a FlowLayout for example, and then add this panel to the SOUTH of your main panel.

Comment: I see how the layout could be improved upon, and you're right. It's not actually pretty, but could this affect the function of the JTextField? Or is it purely cosmetic?

Comment: I don't know, but I would guess that having 5 components painted one above the other would affect the function of the JTextField, yes.

Comment: I've found out that the problem can be solved by simply using a normal TextField instead of a JTextField. Probably it's an issue linked to the usage of the ACM library. This code was for an assignment for CS106A where the instructor sent us a presumably older version of the ACM library. That must have been the problem. Thank you for your help, I'm so glad I finally found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my English - itsn't my first language.
I faced with this "strange behavior" in NameSurfer (Programming Assignments №6 CS106A) when I tried to use JTextField, but in Assignment №7 Section Assignments(the same which author pointed) everything were allright with JTextField.

I noticed that if I use JTextField in NORTH/WEST area JTextField works fine, for SOUTH/EAST I use TextField.